# Create multiple calculated fields at once in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I need to create multiple calculated fields in a tableau workbook. I am currently clicking on 'Create Calculated Field', entering the field name and  calculation then clicking OK.

Since I have around 40 calculated fields to create, I would like create multiple calculated field in one time (via a script or ...) to save time. Any idea if this is possible in Tableau?

Example:

```
**Fields:**

Sales1
Sales2
......
SalesN

Quantity1
Quantity2
......
QuantityN

**Calculated Fields**
AvgPrice 1 = sum(Sales1)/sum(Quantity1)
AvgPrice 2 = sum(Sales2)/sum(Quantity2)
...........................
AvgPrice N = sum(SalesN)/sum(QuantityN)
```

Comment: I use a text editor with multi-cursor like Sublime Text and write the functions there and copy/paste. Hold Alt, click A and then C in tableau and that opens the Calculated field screen.

Comment: But you can only create 1 calculated field at a time with this method. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, that's why I made this a comment and not an answer. Was just giving a tip on how to more quickly make it.

Comment: Thanks. This method is definitely faster! I will use it if bulk creation of calculated fields is not available in Tableau.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you created a single classifier field defining the grouping (your 'N'). You could then allow Tableau to calculate the sales and quantity for each N just by using N as a dimension. This would save a lot of typing.